# angularjs ng options not jumping to option on letter press

Tags: javascript, angularjs, accessibility, ng-options, uiaccessibility

I have a list of objects and using them for ng-options on a select element.

```
  <select class="form-control"
          ng-model="$ctrl.selectedTimeZone"
          name="selectedTimeZone"
          ng-options="option as option.description for option in $ctrl.timeZoneOptions
                                | orderBy: 'description' track by option.name"
          required>
  </select>
```

When a user focuses on the select element and types a letter, i want the first option that matches the letter (normal behavior in normal select elements).

How can i get that functionality back using angularjs ng-options?

Comment: What gets rendered ***is*** a normal select. Really not clear what problem is

Comment: when you type a letter on a focused select element, it jumps to the first option that starts with that pressed letter. that feature seems to be lost when using ng-options.

Comment: Never seen that problem. What browser and version of angular? Provide a demo that reproduces issue. Possibly has something to do with a new rendering based on changing the model but not sure without seeing it occur

Comment: looking into it. my problem is much deeper, i think. each option does not start with a letter exactly (it's a list of timezones following this format: UTC -06:00:00 CST (America/Chicago)). maybe that is the problem. i think i will have to write something custom. thanks

Comment: Quickly found this old demo and seems to work fine for me https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/hCrupm

Comment: I feel that you may have space or something at the beginning of `option.description`.

Comment: Yea, I actually ended up writing something custom and it’s working